# Disable NSS LDAP IPv6 (AAAA) lookups

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, ldap, ipv6, nss

**Question:** How can I disable inet6 AAAA queries for my LDAP server during (LDAP-backed) NSS lookups on a CentOS (RHEL) 5 machine?

**Background:** I've servers configured to consult `ldap://ldap.internal` for NSS *passwd* and *group* lookups.  Every relevant NSS lookup, for example the *getpwuid(3)* implied by an `ls -l` which needs to translate UIDs to network user names, performs the following DNS dance before connecting to the ldap server:

```
AAAA? ldap.internal          -> (no records)
AAAA? ldap.internal.internal -> NXDomain
A?    ldap.internal          -> 192.168.3.89
```

I'd like to skip the first two queries completely.  Configuration:

```
[server]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
[server]$ grep ^passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf 
passwd:     files ldap
[server]$ grep ^uri /etc/ldap.conf
uri ldap://ldap.internal/
```

For what it's worth, IPv6 support is otherwise disabled on these systems:

```
[server]$ grep off /etc/modprobe.conf
alias ipv6 off
alias net-pf-10 off
[server]$ echo "$(ip a | grep -c inet6) IPv6-enabled interfaces"
0 IPv6-enabled interfaces
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the belated downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brief answer is: no, this behavior cannot be changed by simple system configuration.

AAAA lookups are the expected behavior of the shipped *openldap* libraries, *openldap-2.3.43-3.el5* at the time of this writing.  Built with *--enable-ipv6*, the LDAP connection routines resolve hosts with `getaddrinfo(3)` looking for any available address family (`AF_UNSPEC`), and so including both inet4 and inet6.

Now, the *openldap* code is aware of the `AI_ADDRCONFIG` hint, which would prevent looking for inet6 addresses when none are configured on the system, and similarly for inet4 addresses.  However, the code fails to supply this hint for two reasons:

First, and buggily, the hint is misspelled as "AI_ATTRCONFIG" [sic], which misspelling is corrected around 2.4.14.  Second, there is no *configure* test for the viability of this flag, so the code which would supply the flag, misspelled or not, is never compiled in.

Just a little more unneeded network chatter to live with, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `/etc/gai.conf` would have been available in 2009, but it is now (and would appear to have been at least since CentOS 5.5). It is a feature of glibc and allows setting the preference for sorting of IP addresses by `getaddrinfo(3)`.

Look at https://serverfault.com/a/511240/161782 for a full answer with examples.

If you also want to make source address selection have a matching policy, see this post:
http://biplane.com.au/blog/?p=122

Comment: Thanks.  It's not address selection *per se* that I was interested in, but instead the suppression of AAAA lookups.